# Kotlin interface method defaults & transitive dependencies

Tags: kotlin, inheritance, jvm

I've got a system with class/interface hierarchy spread over 3 libraries. The toy version of it looks like this:

In library A:

```
interface BaseInterface {
  fun foo(): String
}
```

In library B:

```
class Impl : BaseInterface {
  override fun foo(): String {
    return "foo!"
  }
}
```

In library C:

```
class SomethingUnrelated {
  fun doAThing() {
     val i: BaseInterface = Impl()
     println(i.foo())
  }
}
```

So far, so good. Library C depends on library B and library A. Everything works fine.

Now say I ship a new version of library A, and I add a new method with a default implementation:

```
interface BaseInterface {
  fun foo(): String
  fun newMethod(): Int = 0
}
```

I want to bring it into library C and change `doAThing` to use it, like this:

```
class SomethingUnrelated {
  fun doAThing() {
     val i: BaseInterface = Impl()
     println(i.foo() + " and also " + i.newMethod())
  }
}
```

If I update library C to bring just in the new version of library A (not touching the dependency on library B), I get a `java.lang.AbstractMethodError` (which is understandable). I could recompile library B and update both A and B at the same time, but I have some other constraints that make that difficult.

So my question is this: do I have any other options here besides recompiling library B and bringing both libraries into C at once? Is there some kotlin magic I can do to help solve my problem?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Depending on your specific case, you can consider using extensions instead of default methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kotlin's default interface methods don't actually compile to Java default interface methods by default. If they did, you wouldn't have gotten the `AbstractMethodError`.

To make Kotlin default methods compile to Java default methods, add the `-Xjvm-default=all` compiler option. Then just clean and recompile library A and C.

When you *do* need to recompile library B, you should also compile it with this option, or mark `BaseInterface` with [`@JvmDefaultWithCompatibility`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.jvm/-jvm-default-with-compatibility/), otherwise it might be binary incompatible.

See also: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/java-to-kotlin-interop.html#default-methods-in-interfaces

Comment: The combination of -Xjvm-default=all and @JvmDefaultWithCompatibility worked pretty well for my use case. Thanks!

Comment: Any idea why is "Kotlin's default interface methods don't actually compile to Java default interface methods by default"?  Is there any constraint in making this the default way, rather than forcing everyone to use xjvm-default=all

Comment: @NickWills I think it is to support older Java versions.